How long did Abimelech reign as king of Gerar?
In Genesis 20:2-4 we read that Abimelech was king of Gerar when Abraham declared Sarah as his sister.
Genesis 20:2- And Abraham said of Sarah his wife, She is my sister: and Abimelech king of Gerar sent, and took Sarah.
NOTE: Isaac was not yet born when this happened.
In Genesis 26:1-9, Isaac presents his wife as his sister. Verse 1 tells us that this happened in Gerar and Abimelech was king of the Philistines.
Genesis 26:1- Later on, a famine swept through the land. This famine was different from the previous famine that had occurred earlier, during Abraham’s lifetime. So Isaac went to Abimelech, king of the Philistines, at Gerar.
Question- Are we talking about the same king who reigned long enough to meet Abraham and his son Isaac, or may we be correct to think that Abimelech was only a royal name and referred to two different kings of Gerar?

There are no historical records for the Philistines in Canaan/Palestine during this period so it is hard to say. Indeed some scholars believe the idea of a Philistine presence in the area during this time to be anachronistic. As far as the biblical narrative is concerned, either Abimelech was long-lived or there were two kings with the same name in this period, probably a father and a son.
Biblical scholars who affirm the documentary hypothesis add that we may actually be dealing with essentially the same story from two different sources. The Interpreter's Bible, for example, states that story of Abraham and Abimelech in Gen 20 is from the "E" source, where "God" is called "elohim." The story of Isaac and Abimelech in Gen. 26 is from the "J" source, where "the LORD" is called "yahweh."

"It was long assumed that there were two Abimelechs, who just happened to be named the same, but then there would also have to be two Phicols. But life spans during the age of the patriarchs were still about twice or three times the human life span of today, and there is no real valid objection to the conclusion that Abimelech and Phicol simply lived that long.
There are also scholars who believe that Abimelech is a royal title instead of a personal name (comparable to Caesar or Pharaoh), and perhaps the "name" Phicol isn't a name either but the Philistine title of army commander. "
-from https://www.abarim-publications.com/Meaning/Phicol.html
